# ffmpeg: How to create an AVIF image with transparent backrgound?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to create an avif image with transparent background. A similar command that I would use to create an PNG image with transparent background doesn't seem to work with avif files:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "color=color=#00000000@0.0:size=550x60,format=yuva420p,drawtext=text='Hello how are you?':fontcolor=black:fontsize=55:borderw=1:bordercolor=white:x=(W-tw)/2:y=(H-th)/2" -frames:v 1 -c:v libaom-av1 hello.avif
```

This results in an image with a black background but I would like it to be transparent...I saw in avif.io that avif images support transparency.

For PNG images the command works:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "color=color=#00000000@0.0:size=550x60,format=yuva420p,drawtext=text='Hello how are you?':fontcolor=black:fontsize=55:borderw=1:bordercolor=white:x=(W-tw)/2:y=(H-th)/2" -frames:v 1 hello.png
```

This is how the image should look like:

[image]

Any ideas on how to make this work with avif images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need ffmpeg 5.1 or newer.

As per the commit, one needs to supply two streams. The first is used for the color data (YUV) and the 2nd is a monochrome single plane to be used as the alpha. The easiest way to do this is to map the video twice and use alphaextract filter on the 2nd one.

e.g.

`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "color=color=#000000@0:size=550x60,format=yuva420p,drawtext=text='Hello how are you?':fontcolor=black:fontsize=55:x=(W-tw)/2:y=(H-th)/2" -map 0 -map 0 -filter:v:1 alphaextract -frames:v 1 -c:v libaom-av1 -still-picture 1 hello.avif`

Comment: Thank you it worked, why is that necessary since you don't need it with  png or webp for example? Would that be something similar to what you have to do with gifs to create a transparent background by creating a color palete and then use it?

Comment: AVIF uses the AV1 codec which does not directly support alpha, only indirectly by signaling that another stream used be used as a matte.