# When converting a PNG with transparency to AVIF with FFmpeg, the transparency is lost

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the following script that converts all PNGs to AVIF in the current directory.

```
#!/bin/zsh

setopt nullglob

for file in *.png; do
  filename="${file%.*}"
  
  ffmpeg -i "$file" -c:v libaom-av1 -pix_fmt yuva420p -lossless 1 -metadata:s:v:0 rotate="" "${filename}.avif"
done

unsetopt nullglob
```

When converting, the alpha channel is lost. How can this be adjusted, is there a specific parameter?

Original image

[image]

AVIF image

[image]

Note that the solution in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1765733/ffmpeg-how-to-create-an-avif-image-with-transparent-backrgound) does not work at all on my question does not work in this case.

Comment: While you say the other answer doesn't help, please demonstrate that. What code did you try after reviewing that answer and how was the result different.